# Error when deploying umbraco project

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, umbraco

I am getting the following error that is causing an error when deploying my Umbraco project.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'filepath\Umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config;\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config'.    Remoo.Umbraco       0

(I have removed the full filepath and put 'filepath' as placeholder).

Has anyone got any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but in general you should not deploy your Install folder at all.  Also are you using any rewrite rules?

Comment: Excellent, I excluded the umbraco folder from the project and tried a deploy and it worked first time. Thanks, I reall appreciate your help!

Comment: Hopefully that was a typo and you excluded install folder not the umbraco folder ;-)  Glad that got it working.